# How to make a counter variable start from 0 for every single object when function is called?

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, colors

I am making a simple website with a bunch of divs in a container. When you click on a div it changes a color. When div is pressed 8 times it goes back to a starting color which is "LightSlateGray". The problem is if someone clicks on another div after clicking on the first one the variable that I used to count the clicks doesn't start from 0.

For example:
First div is clicked and its color changed to red. When the other div is clicked its background color changes to green but I want it to turn red and as user keeps pressing the second div it should turn green the blue then orange etc.

```
var order = 0;
function changeColour(item)
{
    
    order++;
    if(order == 1)
    {
        item.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
    else if(order == 2)
    {
        item.style.backgroundColor = 'Green';
    }
    else if(order== 3)
    {
        item.style.backgroundColor = 'Blue';
    }
    else if(order == 4)
    {
        item.style.backgroundColor = 'Orange';
    }
    else if(order == 5)
    {
        item.style.backgroundColor = 'Yellow';
    }
    else if(order == 6)
    {
        item.style.backgroundColor = 'Purple';
    }
    else if(order == 7)
    {
        item.style.backgroundColor = 'Black';
    }
    if(order == 8)
    {
        item.style.backgroundColor = 'LightSlateGray'
        order = 0
    }
        
}
```

I tried to put var order = 0 in the function itself but that was just dumb because it made other part of code useless

Is there any way of accomplishing that without creating a ton of variables?

Comment: I don’t see how you can control n elements separately without having n counters (or a rather complex counter involving promise which I wouldn’t recommend) You could have the counters as items in an array though which would save code. If you put the colors in an array that would also save code.

Comment: @AHaworth I would like to know that solution of yours. Would you mind?

Comment: If you could make you code into a runnable snippet I could but I am confined to an iPhone at the moment so SO won’t let me create a snippet from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other answers show: You may want to **use an array for the colours** as you essentially refer to them by an index (i.e. `order`).

You want each element to have its own index. You can **use [custom data attributes (`data-*`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)** on each element to let them keep track of their own index:

```js
const colors = ["red","green","blue","orange","yellow","purple","black","lightslategray"];

document.querySelectorAll("#wrapper>div").forEach(div => {
  div.dataset.order = 0;
  div.addEventListener("click", () => changeColor(div));
});

function changeColor(element) {
  let order = Number(element.dataset.order);
  
  element.style.backgroundColor = colors[order];
  
  element.dataset.order = (order + 1) % colors.length;
}
```

```css
#wrapper {border: 1px solid black;width: fit-content}
#wrapper>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

We can also defer the custom attribute's initialization to when we want to change an element's colour. If we then use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) for the click events, we can add more `<DIV>`s without any setup:

```js
const colors = ["red","green","blue","orange","yellow","purple","black","lightslategray"];

const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
wrapper.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  // `evt.target` is the clicked target
  const isChildOfWrapper = evt.target !== wrapper && wrapper.contains(evt.target);
  if (isChildOfWrapper) {
    changeColor(evt.target);
  }
});

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  // No setup required (apart from appending the new element)
  wrapper.append(document.createElement("div"));
});

function changeColor(element) {
  let order = Number(element.dataset.order ?? 0); // Use 0 as fallback
  
  element.style.backgroundColor = colors[order];
  
  element.dataset.order = (order + 1) % colors.length;
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#wrapper>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<button>Add <code>&lt;DIV&gt;</code></button>
```

---

You can also modify [InSync's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76014165/13561410) to use event delegation, as in that solution the elements also keep track of their indices (but encoded as background colours).

Answer (score 1):

You can either create those variables by using [a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const colors = [
  'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Orange',
  'Yellow', 'Purple', 'Black', 'LightSlateGray'
];

document.querySelectorAll('div div').forEach(div => {
  // New 'order' forEach element.
  let order = 0;
  
  div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = colors[order];
    order = (order + 1) % colors.length;
  });
});
```

Try it:

```js
const colors = [
  'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Orange',
  'Yellow', 'Purple', 'Black', 'LightSlateGray'
];

document.querySelectorAll('div div').forEach(div => {
  let order = 0;
  
  div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = colors[order];
    order = (order + 1) % colors.length;
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 2em;
}

div div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  padding: 3em;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

...or use [`Array#indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to have JS do that for you (note that I wrote the color names in lowercase) :

```js
const colors = [
  'red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange',
  'yellow', 'purple', 'black', 'lightslategray'
];

document.querySelectorAll('div div').forEach(div => {
  div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let order = colors.indexOf(this.style.backgroundColor);
    order = (order + 1) % colors.length;
    this.style.backgroundColor = colors[order];
  });
});
```

Try it:

```js
const colors = [
  'red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange',
  'yellow', 'purple', 'black', 'lightslategray'
];

document.querySelectorAll('div div').forEach(div => {
  div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let order = colors.indexOf(this.style.backgroundColor);
    order = (order + 1) % colors.length;
    this.style.backgroundColor = colors[order];
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 2em;
}

div div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  padding: 3em;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be nice to try this.

```
let order = 0;

const orderColor = {
  1: 'red',
  2: 'Green',
  3: 'Blue',
  4: 'Orange',
  5: 'Yellow',
  6:'Purple',
  7:'Black',
  8:'LightSlateGray',
}

function changeColour(item) {
  order++;

  item.style.backgroundColor = orderColor[order]

  if (order === 8) {
    order = 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks really clean but it does the same thing. Order variable is changed whenever div is clicked. The problem is that it isn't equalizing to 0  when other div is being clicked. So color loop doesn't start again. Thanks for your time.